# Sublime text 3 running local file on localhost server using SideBarEnhancements plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to run my index.html file on localhost server because I am using an angular routing directive. These were the steps I used but it is not working.

```js
//sidebarenchancements.json

{
 "file:///C:/Users/Jdog/Desktop/projects/Calibre/social/index.html": {
   "url_testing":"http://localhost",
        "url_production":"http://localhost"
 }
}
```

Please note that the `file:///c:...` is the direct url i see if I run my browser.

Any suggestions? I am using windows 8

Answer (score 0):

for routing issue you can use --disable-web-security flag with chrome for testing and as it done or mozilla firefox because it supports xhr in file:// protocol also  and there are many more ways to do the same